# huwai 1731 ( mobile broadband ) not working with dell inspiron 3521

Tags: wireless, dell

Please help, one of my friend shared this note ( enclosed below), I used these codes and my laptop is able open the data card but I am not getting any signals.

I am able to work with wired connection, but wi-fi and mobile broad band are not working. Please help.

```
sudo apt-get purge usb-modeswitch
sudo apt-get update
sudo spt-get install usb-modeswitch
sudo apt-get update
gksudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
```

Once you enter these above commands 40-usb_modeswitch.rules text file will open.

Then, copy below mentioned lines into  40-usb_modeswitch.rules text file.

```
#Huawei E1731
ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1446", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

Save the file

Then type : `sudo apt-get update`

Then restart the machine.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when i plugged it into `USB 2.0` port.But if its connected to `USB 3.0` port it doesn't recognized as modem.

Answer (score 0):

I just did execute....

```
gksudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
```

and added the following lines (before the last line) end of file.
Saved the file and closed it.
Restarted the machine - That's all.
My Airtel 3G USB Modem HUAWEI E1731 got automatically detected.

Internet worked like a charm.